# Failure to understand some prime sieve syntax

Tags: python, primes, sieve

Could someone walk me line-by line through this prime sieve? I'm attempting to develop my own sieve but most of the faster ones contain syntax that I don't understand (like the lines i've made comments on). Sorry if this is sort of a newbie question -- also if you have any links that could help me with sieve writing they'd be greatly appreciated.

```
def rwh_primes1(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * (n/2) # What does the '[True]' mean?
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i/2]: # The same complaint as in line 3, I don't understand the variable 'sieve'
            sieve[i*i/2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1) # how is sieve used here - it seems to be as a list but i'm unsure
    return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in xrange(1,n/2) if sieve[i]] # 'sieve' is confusing me here yet again.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put the meaning of each line of code in italics, and add my comments in normal-face text.

```
sieve = [True] * (n/2)
```

*Declare a new local variable `sieve` and initialise it to the value `[True] * (n/2)`.* What does that expression mean? `[True]` is a single-element list containing only the Boolean value `True`. Multiplying a list by a number repeats the list, so `sieve` is now an `n/2`-element list of all-`True` values.

```
for i in xrange(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
```

*Start counting in steps of 2, starting at 3 and ending at sqrt(n).* This particular choice of range is an optimisation of the Sieve algorithm: we could count all the way from 1 to n in steps of 1, but that'd be less efficient.

```
if sieve[i/2]:
```

*Look at the `i/2`th element of the `sieve` list. If it's `True`, then continue down the `if` branch.* The author is using `i/2` to compensate for the fact that the code is counting in steps of 2. This way you can work with a shorter list and use less memory.

```
sieve[i*i/2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
```

*Update every i-th element of `sieve` to `False`, starting at i*i/2.* `sieve[i*i/2::i]` is called [*slice notation*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) - because it appears on the left-hand side of an assignment this code will *update* that slice of `sieve`. The right-hand side is a repeat of the list-times-number trick. It computes an all-`False` list of the correct length.

```
return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in xrange(1,n/2) if sieve[i]]
```

This code just turns the `True`/`False` values in `sieve` into a list of prime numbers. The calculation is compensating for the fact that `sieve` doesn't contain any even numbers by multiplying each `True` value's index by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assume n=7:

```
    sieve = [True] * (n/2) # What does the '[True]' mean?
```

Make a list of boolean True values of length half of n. Eg, sieve = [True,True,True] (as 3.5 was a fraction length it would rounded down in python2)

So `xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2)` will be a generator that gives us this sequence: []

```
    for i in 
        if sieve[i/2]: # The same complaint as in line 3, I don't understand the variable 'sieve'
            sieve[i*i/2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1) # how is sieve used here - it seems to be as a list but i'm unsure
    return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in xrange(1,n/2) if sieve[i]] # 'sieve' is confusing me here yet again.
```

When we see [i::2] or somesuch that just meeans we slice the list at recurring intervals. So if mylist contains (0..19):

```
>>> mylist = range(20)
>>> mylist[0::1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> mylist[0::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> mylist[0::3]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

Try playing with this yourself so that you are familiar with it.
So in this case `sieve[i*i/2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)` will be setting every ith value in a list to False.